# Block usages for a terraform 0.11 module to be terraform 0.12 compatible

Tags: terraform

I am converting my terraform module to be 0.12 compatible before moving to 0.12. I was able to fix all the conversions except the some blocks that can be set via a variable.  The module will remain for some time 0.11 but a user of the module can already upgrade to 0.12.

See here my terraform 0.11 fragment.

```
data "aws_ami" "instance" {
  most_recent = true

  filter = "${var.runner_ami_filter}"

  owners = "${var.runner_ami_owners}"
}


variable "ami_filter" {
  type        = "list"

  default = [{
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03*-x86_64-ebs"]
  }]
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to convert the variable `ami_filter` such it will be accepted by 0.12. I complains about the the block definition of the filter.

> An argument named "filter" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a
>   block of type "filter"?

Does anyone have a suggestion how to convert this part of the code to be 0.12 compatible?

Comment: I found this but it seems not to work properly for aws_ami filter.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/attr-as-blocks.html

Answer (score 0):

The construct I am using seems an undocumented feature and not supported anymore.

More details in this issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20505#issuecomment-496601736